# How to add items to dynamically created spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

Hi following is  code to create spinner dynamically, but am confused about how to add data to the generated spinner. Thnx in advance.

```
LinearLayout rAlign = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lId);
    LinearLayout spinnerHolder = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    spinnerHolder.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    spinnerHolder.setLayoutParams(
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        Spinner newSpinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
        newSpinner.setLayoutParams(
            new Spinner.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        newSpinner.setAdapter(options);
        rAlign.addView(spinnerHolder);
        spinnerHolder.addView(newSpinner);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) explain the issue. In general, you need to declare an instance of the interface SpinnerAdapter to handle the options of the Spinner.
You can implement the interface yourself, or use one of the classes: ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter, CursorAdapter, ResourceCursorAdapter, SimpleAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter.
Then just call `spinner.setAdapter()`, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110370/how-do-i-dynamically-update-a-spinner-using-arraylist/12110782#12110782). It will help you how to add items to spinner...It will help you to create adapter and how to add items dynamically to the spinner.